Limits with second order conditions
Let $U$ and $a$ be positive functions such that(with $U$ strictly increasing)
$$\frac{U(ux)-U(x)}{a(x)} \to h_\gamma(u) = \frac{u^\gamma-1}{\gamma}$$ for all $u>0$ as $x \to \infty$, for some $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now, suppose that there exists functions $k$ and positive function $a_2(x)$ such that $a_2(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$ and
$$\frac{U(ux)-U(x)}{a(x)} - h_\gamma(u) \sim a_2(x) k(u), x \to \infty $$
where $f(x) \sim g(x)$ if $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$.
The text says that as long as $k$ is not a multiple of $h_\gamma$, we have either the convergence of $\frac{a_2(ux)}{a_2(x)}$ for all $u>0$ as $x \to \infty$, or equivalently, the convergence of $a_2(x)^{-1}(\frac{l(ux)}{l(x)}-1)$ for all $u>0$, where $l$ is a slowly-varying function(a function $f$ is slowly varying if for all $u>0$, $\frac{f(ux)}{f(x)} \to 1$ as $x \to \infty$).
What I don't understand is

Why can't $k$ be a multiple of $h_\gamma$?

Why are the two conditions equivalent?(i.e. the convergence of $\frac{a_2(ux)}{a_2(x)}$ and the convergence of $a_2(x)^{-1}(\frac{l(ux)}{l(x)}-1)$.

Why does $\frac{U(ux)-U(x)}{a(x)} - h_\gamma(u) \sim a_2(x) k(u), x \to \infty$ imply one of the conditions?


Here is the relevant section of the text:


Thank you.
